# Why will my image not move?

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d, paint, move

I am making a 2d top-down game where the player controls a cat. To do this, the person uses the WASD keys to move. I have Form1, GameManager, Cat, and Moveable classes. Form1 sends GameManager the cat imagelist and e.graphics (for the picturebox). GameManager has a timer and each tick checks to see if the cat has moved. Cat handles the move logic. When I run the program, the cat sprite shows up at its initial position, but does not move upon pressing a key. I can't figure out my issue, could somebody please help?

Here are my classes:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GameManager myGM = new GameManager();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newGame();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.myGM != null)
                this.myGM.paint(e.Graphics);
        }

        public void newGame()
        {
            myGM.newGame(imgCat);
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class GameManager
    {
        Cat ca1 = new Cat();
        int amount = 5;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        public ImageList imgCat = new ImageList();

        public void newGame(ImageList cat)
        {
            imgCat = cat;
            time.Start();
        }

        public void move()
        {
            ca1.Move(amount);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation());
        }

        private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move();
        }
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class Cat: Moveable
    {
        Random myCLoc = new Random();
        private Moveable myCatMove;
        public Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        int dir = 0;

        public void Move(int n)
        {
            if (dir == 0)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y - n;
            }
            if (dir == 1)
            {
                p.X = p.X + n;
            }
            if (dir == 2)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y + n;
            }
            if (dir == 3)
            {
                p.X = p.X - n;
            }
        }
        private void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                dir = 0;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }
        }
        public void changeDirection()
        {

        }

        public Point getLocation()
        {
            return p;
        }

        public void paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Moveable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public interface Moveable
    {
        void Move(int n);
        void changeDirection();
        //Point getLocation();
        void paint(PaintEventArgs e);
    }
}
```

So, I don't have anything calling KeyDown(). How do I make something call KeyDown() if it needs KeyEventArgs e?

Picturebox1 does not have a keydown event, form1 does. I also need to use the keydown event in the cat class so it knows what direction it is facing, so it knows what direction to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no Keyboard event in your code. Could be you left it out (too much code already) but then say something about it.
2. After each `move()` you need to `Invalidate()` the relevant Control, in this case the PictureBox.

Comment: I did not leave out any code. I am confused, do you mean after each move in the GameManager or Cat?

Comment: Well, who calls your `KeyDown()` then?  And Invalidate() after _a_ move, so either one will do I think.

Comment: How do I make something call KeyDown() if it needs KeyEventArgs e?

Comment: Implement `pictureBox1_keyDown`. Just like the paint event.

Comment: pictureBox1 does not have a keydown event, just a previewkey event. I need to use the form1 keydown event

Comment: But I need to do the keydown event from form 1 in the cat class so the cat class knows what direction it is facing

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your classes is getting notification about keydown events.

Either your form1 class should have a handler for keydown and you implement the moving logic there, or your Cat class should derive from System.Windows.Forms.Control implement the keydown handler there.

Then once the new control Cat has focus keypress events will be raised on your control.

Comment: How do I make it so cat derives from system.windows.forms.control?