# I can't get my image to move, using keydown events

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, 2d, picturebox

I am making a 2d top-down game where the player controls a cat. To do this, the person uses the WASD keys to move. I have Form1, GameManager, Cat, and Moveable classes. Form1 sends GameManager the cat imagelist and e.graphics (for the picturebox). GameManager has a timer and each tick checks to see if the cat has moved. Cat handles the move logic. When I run the program, the cat sprite shows up at its initial position, but does not move upon pressing a key. I can't figure out my issue, could somebody please help?

Here are my classes:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GameManager myGM = new GameManager();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            newGame();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.myGM != null)
                this.myGM.paint(e.Graphics);
        }

        public void newGame()
        {
            myGM.newGame(imgCat);
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class GameManager
    {
        Cat ca1 = new Cat();
        int amount = 5;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        public ImageList imgCat = new ImageList();

        public void newGame(ImageList cat)
        {
            imgCat = cat;
            time.Start();
        }

        public void move()
        {
            ca1.Move(amount);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation());
        }

        private void time_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            move();
        }
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace CatAndMouse
{
    class Cat: Moveable
    {
        Random myCLoc = new Random();
        private Moveable myCatMove;
        public Point p = new Point(100, 100);
        int dir = 0;

        public void Move(int n)
        {
            if (dir == 0)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y - n;
            }
            if (dir == 1)
            {
                p.X = p.X + n;
            }
            if (dir == 2)
            {
                p.Y = p.Y + n;
            }
            if (dir == 3)
            {
                p.X = p.X - n;
            }
        }
        private void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                dir = 0;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }
        }
        public void changeDirection()
        {

        }

        public Point getLocation()
        {
            return p;
        }

        public void paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Moveable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatAndMouse
{
    public interface Moveable
    {
        void Move(int n);
        void changeDirection();
        //Point getLocation();
        void paint(PaintEventArgs e);
    }
}
```

So, I don't have anything calling KeyDown(). How do I make something call KeyDown() if it needs KeyEventArgs e?

Picturebox1 does not have a keydown event, form1 does. I also need to use the keydown event in the cat class so it knows what direction it is facing, so it knows what direction to move.

This question DOES NOT have an answer in the other question. That one tells me to fix the keydown event, here I am ask HOW to fix the keydown event!

I REALLY NEED HELP WITH PAINTING THE IMAGE!

Comment: You already have a 2 answers to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234915/why-will-my-image-not-move).  I am flagging this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Brian It does look like the other question asks "why does it not move", as opposed to "how do I recognise a keyboard event?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a misunderstanding of the event mechanism. You appear to have made an event handler for the 'KeyDown' event but not attached it to the event itself.

You need to add the attachment code to the event, like so:

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat();
KeyDown += cat1.cat1_KeyDown;
```

This could be done in the constructor of the form1 class.

You then need to modify the parameters of the event handler in the Cat class to match the event handler signature. e.g.

```
public void cat1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do the movement logic here....
}
```

Comment: It actually appears that the keydown event is linked directly to the cat object, too, meaning it would be impossible to call unless the cat inherits from a GUI based object (I think, at least!)

Comment: Edited to account for this. My mistake.

Comment: Okay, so I have Cat cat1 = new Cat(); and KeyDown += cat1.cat1_KeyDown; in public Form1() and I made cat1_KeyDown with the key code. But nothing is moving!

Comment: did you update the "paint" in GameManager to use cat1's location?

Comment: I have g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation());

Comment: Exactly you need g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], cat1.getLocation()); But also you need to make cat1 accessible from the paint method in the GameManager Class. i.e. instantiate it where you instantiate the ca1 "Cat" object.

Comment: note the difference between ca1 and cat1.

Comment: I am calling the g.DrawImage(imgCat.Images[0], ca1.getLocation()); in the GameManager class, Cat1 is made in Form1. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: ok, my example was just an example. you have a different structure and thus must arrange it differently.

Comment: In your case I would add an event handler to GameManager. I would then attach the 'KeyDown' event of the form to the event handler in GameManager. From there I would call the 'move' method of the Cat object. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I think I got it, How do I make it so my paint method in GameManager keeps repeating? I have to pass it Graphics g.

Comment: The Cat needs to be made in the GameManager. You can use you ca1 instance.

Comment: I mean, how do I make it so my paint method gets repeated every tick?

Comment: I think the form has a 'Paint' event. so you could attach a handler to the paint event in the forms constructor e.g. Paint += form1_paint; and a suitable eventhandler in the form e.g. public void form1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) { //Code here...}. Inside this event handler call the paint method of you GameManager.

Comment: but actually you are already using the PictureBox's paint method to call the paint method of GameManager.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you're using Windows Forms for a game, as opposed to using XNA or something? It would be more appropriate, and it would make this task a LOT easier.

Regarding the question itself, you need to call the forms paint event after moving, and to hook keyboard input you should have an event for the form itself (go to form view, click the lightning bolt in the properties window, look for Keydown). Utilizing this event should allow you to get the output you want.

The method which is called when the event is raised will look a little like this:

```
public void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs ex)
{
    switch (ex.KeyChar) // Get the value of the key pressed
    {
        case 'a':
            // Do stuff if the pressed key is the letter "a"
        case 'b':
            // Do stuff if the pressed key is the letter "b"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to use windows form for a game as per instructions by my teacher. How would I get the direction the cat is going if I used the keydown event in form1?

Comment: There will be some event args passed into the method which is called when the event occurs, I believe they are KeydownEventArgs, they will contain a variable which stores the pressed character. I will update the answer shortly with more information on that

Comment: private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                dir = 0;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                dir = 2;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }

Comment: That will work too, but if you intend to have multiple controls (e.g maybe a button to open an inventory, or one to restart, or one to do anything else) you will likely want to use a switch statement, as they are easier to read and far more suited to multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

- @XtrmJosh is right, XNA would be more appropriate for such task
- You are better off asking such questions in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ than in SO, it is **the** place about game development questions
- Make your cat move in [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) instead, events will be always caught as opposed to using `Control.KeyDown` which catches them **only** if that control has the focus.

Code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        // Move your cat here
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

- When are you hooking to your timer tick event in GameManager ?

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  }

  void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Do your thing
  }
  ```
- In that same tick event you are moving things but **you don't draw them**.
- Use `Cat.Move(int n)` to move your cat, the `Cat.KeyDown` is **irrelevant** unless Cat is a `Control` (it will never get called). But put that logic in the ProcessCmdKey instead. Consider using `Keys` rather than an integer. And the others 'if' should be 'else if'. (see switch instead as it's less error-prone)

Code :

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    // Move your Cat here
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            cat.Move(keyData);
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            break;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

public class Cat
{
    public void Move(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                // act accordingly ...
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valid point about focus there, but if the game doesn't contain buttons and boxes etc, I suppose my method would work. Positive input, +'d.

Comment: For OPs reference, the focus means if you click on a button, then that button becomes focused. This means that the events you would normally pass to the form (e.g a key press event) will be sent to the button object, not to the form object. The result is that the event isn't raised for the form, so using my method you would need to create the event for every control on your form in case it was selected.

Comment: Also, trying not to defend OP too much but oh well, the code he's working with isn't so much related to game development, so I feel he stands much better chances at getting a response here than he would on game development. Primarily because they will pretty much just say what we've hinted at (use XNA)

Comment: Yes I agree with you :-)